# A fragment contains ViewPager is added to back stack

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentmanager

I have a fragment (`HomeFragment`) contains a `ViewPager` of 3 fragments using `FragmentPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager())`. The `HomeFragment` is added to back stack (`addToBackStack(null)`) when a `DetailFragment` is committed to replace the `HomeFragment`. And `onActivityCreated()` of `HomeFragment`, I do :

```
    if (mPagerAdapter == null) {
        mPagerAdapter = new FrgPageAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), mFragments);
        getUpdate();
    }

    mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    ...
```

When press back from detail page, it will display `HomeFragment` as expected and `ViewPager` also can swipe 3 pages but WITH NO 3 fragments in `ViewPager` (That's mean it's blank). How can I fix this?

Comment: can you try changing _FragmentPagerAdapter_ with **FragmentStatePagerAdapter** ?

Comment: Yes I did. Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

ViewPage display one page at a time.it does not show all pages.if you want to show add the child fragments,just layout them will be better.

Comment: I don't think we are on the same page.